# How to convert List to Map - Key of Map should be a combination of multiple keys

Tags: java-8

How to convert List to Map - Key of Map should be a combination of multiple keys

```
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Data
@Builder
public class Student {
    private long id;
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String street;
    private String city;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        List<Student> students = Arrays.asList(
                Student.builder().id(1).firstName("John").lastName("Doe").build(),
                Student.builder().id(1).firstName("Jane").lastName("Doe").build(),
                Student.builder().id(1).firstName("Mike").lastName("Doe").build(),
                Student.builder().id(1).firstName("Jack").lastName("Doe").build()
        );

        LinkedHashMap<Long, String> collect = students.stream()
                .collect(Collectors.toMap(
                        Student::getId, Student::getFirstName, (x, y) -> x + ", " + y, LinkedHashMap::new));
        System.out.println(collect);

        // Answer I am expecting is Ex: {1johnDoe=[id=1,firstName=John, lastName=Doe]}
    }

}
```

Comment: @PAA As per your expected answer which you mentioned like {1johnDoe=[id=1,firstName=John, lastName=Doe]} } - > you are adding key as combination of id+firstName+lastName and value as an Student Object, is this correct expectations ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Using Java 17**

*I have implemented the below code using some of the **latest java features** apart from Java 8.*

> **Records in java 14 :** As of JDK 14, we can replace our `data classes` with records. Records are **immutable classes** that require only the type and name of fields. We **do not need to** create constructor, getters, setters, override toString() methods, override hashcode and equals methods.

> **List.of() in java 9:** It is a `static method` that returns the **immutable list of elements** passed as arguments. Here in the below scenario, we will get the list of four student objects.

```
public class Test {
      public static void main(String[] args) {
    
        record Student(long id, String firstName, String lastName,String street, String city){}
    
        Student s1 = new Student(1,"F1","L1","S1","C1");
        Student s2 = new Student(2,"F2","L2","S2","C2");
        Student s3 = new Student(3,"F3","L3","S3","C3");
        Student s4 = new Student(4,"F4","L4","S4","C4");
    
        Map<String,Student> output =
            List.of(s1,s2,s3,s4).stream().collect(Collectors.toMap(x -> x.id() + x.firstName(),
                Function.identity(), (k, v) -> k, LinkedHashMap::new));
    
        System.out.println(output);
      }
    }
```

**Output:**

```
{1F1=Student[id=1, firstName=F1, lastName=L1, street=S1, city=C1], 2F2=Student[id=2, firstName=F2, lastName=L2, street=S2, city=C2], 3F3=Student[id=3, firstName=F3, lastName=L3, street=S3, city=C3], 4F4=Student[id=4, firstName=F4, lastName=L4, street=S4, city=C4]}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do as follows

```
LinkedHashMap<String, Student> collect = students.stream()
.collect(
    Collectors.toMap(
    student->(String.join("", Long.toString(student.getId()),student.getFirstName(),student.getLastName())),
    student->student,
    (v1,v2)->v1,
    LinkedHashMap::new));
        
collect.forEach((k,v)->System.out.println(k+"="+v));
```

I think, you want key as String and value as Student into map